# TikZ: Upper envelope of smooth curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw two curves using

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=line 1] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1, 0)};
\draw[name path=line 2] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5, 0) (1,1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and they intersect at least once:

How can I draw their upper envelope? If the curves were the graphs of known functions `f(x)` and `g(x)`, I could just plot `max(f(x),g(x))`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Your MWE should compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\clip` does wonderful things.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip[name path=line 1] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1, 0)} -- (1,1)--(0,1)--(0,0);
\draw[name path=line 2] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5, 0) (1,1)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip[name path=line 3] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5, 0) (1,1)} -- (0,1)--(0,0);
\draw[name path=line 4] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1, 0)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If would be so nice if we could store paths in tikz like we can in Metapost.....